# PList - TextMate says OK, XCode says it's corrupted

Tags: xcode, plist, textmate

I was trying to edit a Plist file using it's Source Code, but for some reason XCode is telling me this file is corrupted.
I checked this file with TextMate, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787525/editing-root-plist-as-source-code-results-in-corrupted-plist). TextMate says my file is OK, so what could possibly be wrong?

File structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array> 
        <dict>
            <key>Ave</key>
            <string>acauã</string>
            <key>Texto</key>
            <string>(Habitat – Comum em borda de floresta, capoeira, mata de galeria, campo, cerrado, áreas alagadas em geral. Prefere o estrato médio e as copas. Característica – Tem plumagem branca e asa marrom-escura, além de uma faixa preta no rosto, envolvendo os olhos, que parece maquiagem de roqueiro das antigas. O bico é amarelo, com a ponta preta. Pode chegar a 52 cm. Comportamento – O nome vem do canto, que segundo lendas diversas, pode prenunciar a morte ou a chegada de forasteiros. Come lagarto, morcego, cobra e parasita de gado. Faz ninho em buraco de árvore.</string>
            <key>Taxon</key>
            <string>Águias, Falcões</string>
            <key>Cor</key>
            <string>5</string>
            <key>CorSecundaria</key>
            <string>8</string>
            <key>Bico</key>
            <string>11</string>
            <key>Cauda</key>
            <string>17</string>
            <key>Corpo</key>
            <string>20</string>
            <key>Risco</key>
            <string>fora de perigo</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Ave</key>
            <string>acurana</string>
            <key>Texto</key>
            <string>Habitat – Mata ribeirinha, igapó, mangues, buritizais, ilhas fluviais e áreas alagadas em geral, geralmente no estrato médio. Característica – Plumagem predominantemente castanha, com detalhes em tom canela, toda malhada, lembrando uma coruja. O macho, de 28 cm, tem cauda mais longa, com penas brancas na parte externa. A fêmea, de 23 cm, é mais escura. Comportamento – Tem hábitos noturnos, voando curtas distâncias para capturar insetos. Descansa de dia. Pousa em galhos e faz ninho escavando a areia, onde põe 2 ovos.</string>
            <key>Taxon</key>
            <string>Bacuraus</string>
            <key>Cor</key>
            <string>7</string>
            <key>CorSecundaria</key>
            <string>5</string>
            <key>Bico</key>
            <string>9</string>
            <key>Cauda</key>
            <string>13</string>
            <key>Corpo</key>
            <string>19</string>
            <key>Risco</key>
            <string>fora de perigo</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

Regards,

Claudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your plist file itself is actually saved as UTF-8, otherwise your special characters won't be read correctly.